# "Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar." in combined Clojure + Clojurescript re-frame project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, re-frame

I have developed over 30 Clojure projects, but this is my first foray into Clojurescript. I built a SPA using re-frame and now I am attempting to create the uberjar for it. When I run `lein uberjar`, I get the following error message:

> Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar. It
>   may not be executable as expected. A gen-class directive may be
>   missing in the namespace which contains the main method, or the
>   namespace has not been AOT-compiled.

I've setup the server-side section of the `project.clj` similar to other Clojure projects.

- All server-side source files are located in `src/clj`.
- All Clojurescript source files are located in `src/cljs`
- `main` is located in a file `server_core.clj`, which resides in `src/clj/ordering`.
- `(:gen-class)` is present in `server_core.clj`.
- The `-main` exists within `server_core.clj`:

  (defn -main
    [& args]
    (main))
- `project.clj` includes the following directive for the uberjar:

  ```
  :uberjar {:aot :all
            :source-paths ["src/clj"]
            :env {:production true}
            :main ordering.server-core
            :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]}}
  ```
- The `main` and `target-path` directives in `project.clj` are as follows:

  ```
  :main ^:skip-aot ordering.server-core
  :target-path "target/%s")
  ```

I would like to create this uberjar to include in the Dockerfile as I do with other Clojure projects.

**UPDATE: ADD project.clj**

```
(defproject ordering "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure             "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript       "1.10.238"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async          "0.4.474"]

                 ;; clojurescript 3rd party                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                 [re-frame/re-frame               "0.10.5"]
                 [day8.re-frame/test              "0.1.5"]
                 [day8.re-frame/http-fx           "0.1.6"]
                 [re-frame-datatable              "0.6.0"]
                 [com.rpl/specter                 "1.1.1"]
                 [cljsjs/firebase                 "3.5.3-0"]
                 [reagent                         "0.8.0"]
                 [expound                         "0.6.0"]
                 [metosin/reitit                  "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [metosin/reitit-ring             "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [metosin/reitit-spec             "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [metosin/muuntaja                "0.5.0"]
                 [cljs-ajax                       "0.7.3"]
                 [re-com                          "2.1.0"]
                 [garden                          "1.3.5"]
                 [ring-logger-timbre                               "0.7.5"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter                          "1.6.2"]

                 ;; common                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                 [clj-time                                         "0.13.0"]
                 [cheshire                                         "5.7.1"]
                 [com.taoensso/timbre                              "4.10.0"]
                 [commons-codec/commons-codec                      "1.11"]

                 ;; google                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                 [com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage            "1.27.0"]
                 [com.google.firebase/firebase-admin               "6.0.0"]

                 [ns-tracker                      "0.3.1"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7"]
            [lein-garden    "0.3.0"]
            [lein-ring      "0.9.7"]]

  :ring {:init ordering.server-core/init
         :destroy ordering.server-core/destroy
         :handler ordering.handler/app
         :auto-reload? true
         :port 3000
         :nrepl {:start? true}}

  :min-lein-version "2.5.3"

  :source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/clj"]
  :test-paths ["test/cljs" "test/clj"]

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js/compiled" "target"
                                    "test/js"
                                    "resources/public/css"]

  :figwheel {:css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]}

  :garden {:builds [{:id           "screen"
                     :source-paths ["src/styles"]
                     :stylesheet   ordering.screen/screen
                     :compiler     {:output-to     "resources/public/css/screen.css"
                                    :pretty-print? true}}]}

  :prep-tasks [["garden" "once"]]

  :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}

  :profiles
  {:dev
   {:dependencies [[fipp/fipp                       "0.6.12"]
                   [binaryage/devtools              "0.9.10"]
                   [figwheel-sidecar                "0.5.16"]
                   [re-frisk                        "0.5.4"]
                   [com.cemerick/piggieback         "0.2.2"]
                   [doo                             "0.1.10"]
                   [javax.servlet/servlet-api       "2.5"]
                   [clj-http                        "3.9.0"]
                   [ring/ring-mock                  "0.3.1"]]

    :plugins      [[lein-figwheel                   "0.5.16"]
                   [lein-doo                        "0.1.10"]]
    }

   :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]

   :uberjar {:aot :all
             :source-paths ["src/clj"]
             :env {:production true}
             :main ordering.server-core
             :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]}}

  :cljsbuild
  {:builds
   [{:id           "dev"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :figwheel     {:on-jsload            "ordering.core/mount-root"}
     :compiler     {:main                 ordering.core
                    :closure-defines      {"goog.DEBUG" true
                                           "clairvoyant.core.devmode" true}
                    :output-to            "resources/public/js/compiled/dev/app.js"
                    :output-dir           "resources/public/js/compiled/dev/out"
                    :asset-path           "js/compiled/dev/out"
                    :source-map-timestamp true
                    :preloads             [devtools.preload
                                           re-frisk.preload]
                    :external-config      {:devtools/config {:features-to-install :all}}
                    }}

    {:id           "min"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :compiler     {:main                 ordering.core
                    :output-to            "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js"
                    :output-dir           "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                    :optimizations        :advanced
                    :asset-path           "js/compiled/out"
                    :closure-defines      {goog.DEBUG false}
                    :pretty-print         false}}

    {:id           "test"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs" "test/cljs"]
     :compiler     {:main          ordering.runner
                    :output-to     "resources/public/js/compiled/test.js"
                    :output-dir    "resources/public/js/compiled/test/out"
                    :optimizations :none}}
    ]}

  :doo {:build "test"
        :alias {:default [:chrome]}}

  :main ^:skip-aot ordering.server-core
  :target-path "target/%s")
```

Comment: Could be nothing, but seems like the namespace of server-core based on the location of server_core.clj would be "ordering". But the :main in the :uberjar profile points to "annotation-client.server-core". Could that be an issue?

Comment: @jas, you are correct. I had typed them incorrectly in the SO post. I have updated to reflect the correct names. I added the full `project.clj` Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why `skip-aot`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the cause of your specific problem, but I also just recently started using CLJS and [created a template project](https://github.com/cloojure/cljs-template) that works with both the `doo` testing framework & figwheel.

```
~/expr/cljs-template > lein doo phantom test once

;; ======================================================================
;; Testing with Phantom:

doorunner - beginning
doorunner - end

Testing tst.flintstones.dino
Beginning dino tests...
globalObject:   #js {:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
(-> % .-b (+ 5) => 7
(js/makeDino) => #js {:desc blue dino-dog, :says #object[Function]}
dino.desc =>  blue dino-dog
dino.says(5) =>  Ruff-Ruff-Ruff-Ruff-Ruff!
Finished dino tests...

Testing tst.flintstones.wilma
Beginning wilma tests...
Finished wilma tests...
Beginning wilma tests...
wilmaPhony/stats:    #js {:lipstick red, :height 5.5}
wilma => #js {:desc patient housewife, :says #object[Function]}
Finished wilma tests...

Testing tst.flintstones.pebbles
Beginning pebbles tests...
Finished pebbles tests...

Ran 5 tests containing 10 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

It also works with `lein uberjar`:

```
~/expr/cljs-template > lein uberjar
Created /home/alan/expr/cljs-template/target/flintstones-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /home/alan/expr/cljs-template/target/flintstones-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

You may be able to spot the difference vs your project by eye, or you could incrementally paste in your code with frequent pauses for `lein clean; lein uberjar` to see when something new causes it to fail.  Be sure to do the `clean` step whenever in doubt, and also every time you change `project.clj`, or else old build artifacts could really muck things up.

I would be interested in what you discover as the cause.

Comment: very helpful input. I will try that and let you know how it goes.